# Windows Web server 2008

Tags: ping

I have a online Windows web server with Plesk as control panel. I have full access to my server by remote admin. I want to stop the ping attack on server by some people or all. Kindly guide how can I stop other people from pinging my web server.

Comment: What's a 'ping attack'?

Comment: Can you configure your firewall?

Answer (score 2):

A commonly heard objection to allowing ICMP Echo Replies is that it gives away information to hackers that there is a live connection on this IP address. Such objections are not well-founded, and can be safely ignored.

There is no evidence in practice that any hacker has been aided by the presence of an ICMP Echo Reply.

Hackers do not typically write code that tests an address with ICMP Echo before launching a hostile probe: they always send the hostile probe directly: either it works or it doesn't, and information from ICMP adds nothing to the analysis.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Windows' built-in firewall to block certain connections, and this is certainly a good thing to do on a public web server which doesn't have other firewalls protecting it (think about Remote Desktop); but I personally wouldn't bother blocking pings: they are absolutely harmless, and a useful tool for troubleshooting network problems.